# Migration from Magento 1 to Magento 2. Import tool question

Tags: magento2, import, order-status

Importing orders in 2 steps. Step 1 is all orders prior to migration. Step 2 is puting server in maintenance mode and importing delta orders. Will Magento import tool also update statuses of step 1 orders ?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **YES**

in Magento 1 db, there are table like`m2_cl_...` where they maintain new changes after initial migration

In DB, also maintain `operation` and `processed` for each table..You can see `operation` can have `insert` and `update` option.

So for existing orders, it will perform update and for new insert

Hope above will answer your query!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `bin/magento migrate:delta` command will migrate order data changes as well as new orders.